# Why Is My Feed2JS RSS Feed Working Locally But Not After Deployed? (GitHub Pages)

Tags: javascript, html, dns, rss, github-pages

I'm using [feedtojs.org](https://feed2js.org/) to populate a feed of my Medium blog posts to my GitHub Pages site. For some reason, it is working totally fine on my local server, but not on the domain itself. The RSS feed is valid.

Here is how it looks on my local server:

[image: Working RSS Feed]

Here is how it looks when loaded on the actual domain:

[image: Not Working RSS Feed]

Here is the link to my [website](https://coltonkaiser.dev) (in case it helps for reference/context)

Here is my code (copy-pasted directly from the build instructions on feed2js):

```
    <script language="JavaScript" 
            src="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Ffeed%2F%40coltonkaiser&chan=title&date=y&targ=y&utf=y"  
            charset="UTF-8" 
            type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <a href="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Ffeed%2F%40coltonkaiser&chan=title&date=y&targ=y&utf=y&html=y">
           View RSS feed
        </a>
    </noscript>
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: look in the browsers *developer* tools console - and show any errors you see in the question

Comment: if your website is https (hint: it is), then you'll HAVE to use https for that script url, not http - you should see an error in the browsers *developer* tools console regarding this exact thing

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! I'll post that as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x)'s solution worked. Simply needed to change the script URL to https. Works like a charm now